# AcquireToken(string resource, string clientId, UserCredential userCredential) not working for Azure Authentication

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-authentication

Using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory(2.22.302111727) I am trying to get the access token and the refresh token via ADAL AcquireToken(resourceUri, new ClientCredential(clientId,clientSecret) but I am able to get the only access token only but when I am using the same app with AcquireToken(resourceUri, clientId, userCredential) and passing the username and password as the userCredentials then I am able to get both the access as well as refresh token.

```
string resourceUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
string clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


 AuthenticationResult token = authContext.AcquireToken(resourceUri, new 
ClientCredential(clientId,clientSecret));

string resourceUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
string clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


AuthenticationResult token = authContext.AcquireToken(resourceUri, new 
ClientCredential(clientId,clientSecret));
```

I have also tried using AcquireToken(clientId, resourceUri, new Uri(redirectUri)) but it gives me error  "AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'" and I have tried AcquireToken(resourceUri, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri),
                    PromptBehavior.RefreshSession ,new UserIdentifier("xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx", UserIdentifierType.UniqueId)) and it gives me error "AADSTS650057: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Client app ID: 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000(Microsoft Graph)."
Please explain the exact resource value that is missing here in error AADSTS650057.

Answer (score 1):

You may be hitting several different error. OAuth2 client credentials grant does not return refresh tokens ([enter link description here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.3) ) as you can get a new token with the existing credentials. Requests involving user credentials do return refresh tokens as you may want to renew the access token without having to prompt the user for credentials.

AADSTS650057 is most likely caused by your application being registered in AAD without having permission to call MS Graph. An application must have either Application Permission (when using Client Credentials) or Delegated Permission (when using user creds) to get a token to this resource.

Answer (score 0):

1.Install this from nuget package
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
2. add this code

```
  string clientId = "Get it from Admin"
  string clientSecret = "Get it from Admin"
  string authorityUrl = "Get it from Admin"
  string authorityId = "Get it from Admin";

string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", authorityId);

var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithAuthority(authority).WithClientSecret(clientSecret).Build();
var authResult = Task.Run(() => app.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { $"{apiEndpointUrl}/.default" }).ExecuteAsync()).Result;
return authResult.AccessToken;
```